# Automatically show data based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php

Basically, I have a table with two column: 'Kode Barang' (Item ID) and 'Nama Barang' (Name of Item). The first column is a dropdown option which it's data get populated dynamically from another table. If a user select an Item ID, then the second column will automatically show the name of the item.

Let's say that I've only two row as this code below:

```
<HTML>
<table id="theTable" border="1">

<thead>
    <tr>
        <th> Kode Barang </th>
        <th> Nama Barang </th>
    <tr> 
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td type="text" name="kode_barang" id="kode_barang"/readonly>
            <?php  
                mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
                mysql_select_db("skripsi_1");  
                $result = mysql_query("select * from input_data_barang");  
                $jsArray = "var kode_barang = new Array();\n";  
                echo '<select name="kode_barang" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">';  
                echo '<option></option>';  
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                echo '<option value="' . $row['kode_barang'] . '">' . $row['kode_barang'] . '</option>';  
                $jsArray .= "kode_barang['" . $row['kode_barang'] . "'] = {name:'" . addslashes($row['nama_barang']) . "',desc:'".addslashes($row['nama_barang'])."'};\n";  
                } 
                echo '</select>';  
            ?>  
        </td>

        <td><input type="text" name="nama_barang" id="nama_barang"/readonly>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                <?php echo $jsArray; ?>
                function changeValue(id){
                document.getElementById('kode_barang').value = kode_barang[id].name;
                document.getElementById('nama_barang').value = kode_barang[id].desc;
                };
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td type="text" name="kode_barang" id="kode_barang"/readonly>
                            <?php  
                mysql_connect("localhost","root","");  
                mysql_select_db("skripsi_1");  
                $result = mysql_query("select * from input_data_barang");  
                $jsArray = "var kode_barang = new Array();\n";  
                echo '<select name="kode_barang" onchange="changeValue(this.value)">';  
                echo '<option></option>';  
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
                    echo '<option value="' . $row['kode_barang'] . '">' . $row['kode_barang'] . '</option>';  
                    $jsArray .= "kode_barang['" . $row['kode_barang'] . "'] = {name:'" . addslashes($row['nama_barang']) . "',desc:'".addslashes($row['nama_barang'])."'};\n";  
                } 
                echo '</select>';  
                ?>  
        </td>

        <td><input type="text" name="nama_barang" id="nama_barang"/readonly>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php echo $jsArray; ?>
            function changeValue(id){
            document.getElementById('kode_barang').value = kode_barang[id].name;
            document.getElementById('nama_barang').value = kode_barang[id].desc;
            };
            </script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</HTML>
```

The first row works perfectly. The problem is in the second row. If I select an option from the dropdown, then name of the item doesn't appear in the second row, but appear in the first row instead. Would anybody please show me how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: the `mysql_*` api functions are deprecated - you should upgrade your code to either `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are appending your values using:

```
document.getElementById('kode_barang').value = kode_barang[id].name;
document.getElementById('nama_barang').value = kode_barang[id].desc;
```

The problem is, that there is an Element with the ID kode_barang/nama_barang in BOTH rows. So you have 2 Elements for the ID's. Javascript appereantly just decides only to take the first one. Just rename them in the second row to "kode_barang2" and "nama_barang2" and when setting the values change the names too:

```
document.getElementById('kode_barang2').value = kode_barang[id].name;
document.getElementById('nama_barang2').value = kode_barang[id].desc;
```

Comment: I've tried, but the problem become reversed. The second row works perfectly, the first one is not. If I select an option from the first row, the name appear in the second row.

Comment: Okay the second problem is that you have got 2 functions that are both called changeValue(id). You can't do that! Rename the second one to changeValue2(id) and of course also change the calls

Comment: Do you mean like this: function changeValue2(id){ document.getElementById('kode_barang2').value[2] = kode_barang[id].name; document.getElementById('nama_barang2').value[2] = kode_barang[id].desc;        I'm sorry, I'm a noob.

Comment: By doing that, the problem back to the first. Name of the item only appear in the first row.

Comment: Don't replace the id, that doesn't make any sense. Where are you calling your change-Value functions?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Pardon me

Comment: Finally, it's working. Basti, I'm very grateful for your help. Thank you very very much.